# The structure $(\mathbb N, <, f)_{f\in \mathcal F}$ seems to have no elementary extension

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

This is exercise 2.3.1 (2) from Tent/Ziegler, [A Course in Model Theory](https://books.google.de/books?id=D9sClsdErEsC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. Show that $(\mathbb N, <, f)_{f\in \mathcal F}$ has no countable proper elementary extension.

My approach was to assume we have some proper elementary extension $\mathfrak A$ with $\mathbb N \subsetneq A$. Choose $a \in A \setminus \mathbb N$. As we have a first order sentences true in $\mathbb N$ stating that there is no maximal element, either $a$ is between two natural numbers $n,m$ with $m = n+1$, or comes before every natural number. In the first case let $\overline n, \overline m : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ the constant function giving $n$ and $m$. Then in $(\mathbb N, <, f)_{f\in \mathcal F}$ the sentence $\exists x \forall y ( \overline n(y) < x < \overline m(y) )$ is false, but in $\mathfrak A$ it is true. Hence this case could not arise. Similar if $a$ comes before every natural number, using $\overline 0 : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ I can give a sentence true in this extension, but not true in $\mathbb N$.

So, in consequence there would be no elementary extension at all. But this contradicts the Theorem stated on [these slides](http://bvans.net/mecmc/slides_kossak_121001.pdf) (see slide number 7), that every infinite model has a proper elementary extension.

So what is wrong with my above reasoning? Why this contradiction?

Comment: "Either $a$ is between two natural numbers $n$, $m$ with $m=n+1$, or comes before every natural number". What?? Exactly the opposite is true! It's true that $\mathbb{N}\models \forall x\, \exists y\, (x<y)$ (there is no maximal element), so $\mathfrak{A}$ also satisfies this sentence. But this doesn't rule out having an element of $\mathfrak{A}$ which is bigger than all elements of $\mathbb{N}$ - it's just that there also have to be even bigger elements of $\mathfrak{A}$!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here. Let $\mathcal{M} = (\mathbb{N}, < f)_{f \in \mathcal{F}}$. We want to show that if $\mathcal{M} \prec \mathcal{N}$, then $|\mathcal{N}| > \aleph_0$ (by upward Löwenheim–Skolem/Ultrapower construction, we know such $\mathcal{N}$ exists).  Any element in $a \in \mathcal{N} \backslash \mathcal{M}$ will be **greater** than any natural number (in above, you say that it must be less than any natural number or inbetween two of them).

Now, one has to show that $|\mathcal{N}| > \aleph_0$. Choose $a \in \mathcal{N} \backslash \mathcal{M}$.  We know that $M \models \forall x \exists y f(x) = y$ for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$. Since $M \prec \mathcal{N}$, we know that for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$, $f(a) \in \mathcal{N}$. Now, it's your job to show that $|\mathcal{N}| > \aleph_0$.

(As a hint, you **need** to somehow incorporate the ordering.)

Comment: The set of monotone functions is uncountable, and for a monotone function $f$ I would have $f(a) \in \mathcal N \setminus \mathcal M$. If I can show that all these values $f(a)$ are distinct for different $f$ this would give the result, but I guess this does not hold. So do you have one hint more how to proceed?

Comment: @StefanH (1) Find an uncountable subfamily $\mathcal F_0\subseteq\mathcal F$ with the following property: for every two different $f,q\in\mathcal F_0$, there is $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $f(n)\neq g(n)$ holds for all $n>n_0$. (2) Conclude that for different $f,g\in\mathcal F_0$, $f(a)\neq g(a)$.