# Upward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem for uncountable signatures

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a first-order theory with arbitrarily large finite models. It is true that $\mathcal{T}$ has models of every infinite cardinality? If the signature is countable, the answer is yes by the compactness theorem and Löwenheim–Skolem theorem. But if the signature is uncountable, it's unclear to me what happens for infinite cardinalities smaller than the size of the signature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complementing Greg Nisbet's answer, here's a proof that $\beth_1$ is the best one can do (this is a quick modification of the usual example of a countably infinite structure with no countable proper elementary extension.):

Let $A_n$ be the linear order with $n$ elements. Let $B_n$ be the binary tree of height $n$, viewed as a structure in the language consisting of a constant $o$ naming the root, two successor relations $S_0$ and $S_1$ (left and right successor, respectively), and the "is a prefix of" relation. For each $r\in 2^\mathbb{N}$, let $U_r$ be a unary relation symbol. Finally, let $E$ be a binary relation symbol and consider the following two-sorted theory $T$:

- The common theory of the $A_n$s holds on the first sort and the common theory of the $B_n$s holds on the second sort.
- Via $E$, the first sort "counts" the levels of the second sort. E.g. $o$ is the unique thing which $E$ pairs with the smallest element of the first sort, and the children of $\sigma$ get $E$-paired with the successor of the thing $\sigma$ gets $E$-paired with.
- Each $U_r$ names a maximal chain in the tree: if $U_r(\sigma)$ and $U_r(\tau)$ then $\sigma\preccurlyeq\tau$ or $\tau\preccurlyeq\sigma$, and each point on the first sort gets $E$-paired with some $\sigma$ with $U_r(\sigma)$.
- For each $r\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and each finite binary string $\sigma\prec r$, the axiom "If $\sigma$ exists, then $U_r(\sigma)$." Here "$\sigma$ exists" is shorthand, expressed in terms of the successor relations; e.g. "$0110$ exists" is really $$\exists x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4(oS_0x_1\wedge x_1S_1x_2\wedge x_2S_1x_3\wedge x_3S_0x_4),$$ and $x_4$ is the node corresponding to $0110$.

Now any infinite model of the above theory must have continuum-many elements. One key point is that since all the $A_n$s have a greatest element, the full binary tree of height $\omega$ is **not** (the tree part of) a model of this theory. Once we go infinite at all, we have to go all the way to $\beth_1$.

Comment: @tomasz I did mention it; that's exactly the content of "One key point is that ... all the $A_n$s have a greatest element."

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood that part. My bad

Comment: Thank you, Noah. Since you call this a modification of a usual example, do you have a reference to such an example?

Comment: @BPP I think it is, in some form or other, in most model theory books. See e.g. Tent/Ziegler, cited in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038313/the-structure-mathbb-n-f-f-in-mathcal-f-seems-to-have-no-elementary.

Answer (score 6):

Using an [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on an ascending sequence of finite models I can get a relatively small infinite model (whose size does not depend on the language), but not (yet) a countable model like I would like.

---

Let $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_3$ and so on be a sequence of finite models of ascending size.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.

We can construct the ultrapower $(\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} M_i)/\mathcal{U}$. Call it $A$.

The elements of $A$, before they're lashed together by $\mathcal{U}$ are sequences of natural numbers where each position has a fixed upper bound. Therefore $|A|$ is at most $\beth_1$.

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't have arbitrarily large finite models, as required by the question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber. Robert was right. I edited my answer heavily based on his comment. For the first version I tried to do the standard “many many non-equal constant symbol” trick. Robert rightly pointed out that this ignored part of the question.

Comment: @GregNisbet Whoops, missed the edit history!

Comment: In Noah's defense, I think in cases like this (where you just do a completely different thing from what you originally posted) you should really just delete the answer and post a new one.

Comment: Sorry. I really didn’t intend my comment to be rude. I just wanted to point out that Robert correctly identified a huge flaw in what I posted originally.